# Resharper: I want all blocks in braces

Tags: resharper

I want to tell Resharper that if I have anything like

```
if (foo) { bar(); }
```

to turn it into

```
if (foo)
{
   bar();
}
```

But I can't find the setting nor info on their support site.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open your R# settings, go to *ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Syntax Style* and set *Braces | In "if" statement* to *Enforce always*:
[image]

Furthermore you have to go to *ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping* and disable *Arrangement of embedded blocks | Keep existing arrangement of embedded blocks*:
[image]